# Using the MySQL select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select the posts from users based on who the logged in user is following. What would I need to do? How do I use two different tables with one SELECT statement? I don't even know where to start.

I have 3 tables:
users
posts
followers

Thanks.

Comment: what is your table structure ?

Comment: Please provide the SQL of your table creation, then it's possible to help.  But the gist of it is that you do a JOIN using foreign and primary keys.

Comment: This seems like it was answered for you in detail a hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321532/using-an-array-in-an-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    followers f
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.author = f.following_id
WHERE   f.user_id = $logged_in
ORDER BY
        p.post_date DESC
```

I had to make up the field names as you haven't provided them.

Comment: Hi Quassnoi, if wanted to get the user own posts along with those they are following, how would i add that to your query? Thanks :)

Comment: @SaffronHarris: please post it as another question.

Comment: Thank, i've posted it on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502671/ar-get-own-posts-and-friends-posts

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Join query as Quassonoi suggested in his answer, If you want to try an alternate solution, you can do it with subquery like this

```
SELECT P.PostId,P.Title,P.Body
FROM Post P WHERE P.CreatedById 
IN ( 
    SELECT FollowerID from Followers WHERE USER_ID=3
   )
```

Replace `3` with the current user id. Assuming your table structure is something like this.

**POST**

```
PostId (int)
Title 
Body
```

**Followers**

```
UserId (int)
FollowerId (int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting from two tables is done using JOINs
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

basically you select from two tables and define JOIN condition.

Assume you have two tables:

- users with columns: user_id, user_name, online_state
- posts with columns: post_id, user_id (user who posted this post), title, message

SELECT p.title, p.message FROM users u JOIN posts p ON u.user_id = p.user_id WHERE u.online_state = 'online'

join condition should be after ON, non-join condition after WHERE

Comment: you could also do SELECT ... FROM table JOIN table2 ON condition JOIN table3 ON condition JOIN table4 ON condition.

Comment: joins are preferred over subqueries because you don't force database to evaluate whole subquery, and especially using dependent subqueries is evil