# AR get own posts and friends posts

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have these tables;

```
user - contains user_id | username | fullname | email etcc
user_followers - contains follow_id| user_id | follower_id | date etcc
posts - contains post_id | user_id | post | post_date
```

I’m trying to grab all the posts by the users the user is following and the user’s own posts.

I’ve tried

```
$this->db->select('posts.*')->from('posts')
        ->join('user_followers', 'user_followers.user_id = posts.user_id', 'INNER')
        ->where('user_followers.follower_id', $user_id)->order_by('posts.post_date','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

But the problem is, i’m not able to get the user’s posts from this query. I’ve tried other methods with or_where etc and i was able to get the user’s posts, only that the data was tripled :(
Can someone please help me out here?
Many Thanks in advance.

Oh in normal Mysql, its;

```
SELECT  posts.*
FROM    posts
JOIN    user_followers
ON      user_followers.user_id = posts.user_id
WHERE   user_followers.follower_id = $user_id
ORDER BY
    posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: does the 'normal' mysql query work?

Comment: You could just split the query into two queries, and store the results in the same array.

Comment: Hmm that's not a bad idea too.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

->where() supports passing any string  to it and it will use it in the query, provided you pass a second and third parameter of NULL and FALSE respectively. This tells CI not to escape the query.
E.g.

```
$where_query = "p.user_id = $user_id OR p.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_followers WHERE follower_id = $user_id)";
->where($where_query,NULL,FALSE);
```

Alternatively, you could check out this subquery library https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Subqueries

Comment: Note that this will involve a fullscan on `posts` since in `MySQL` the `IN` construct always makes the outer table leading.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    user_followers
        WHERE   follower_id = $user_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  $user_id
        ) uf
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.user_id = uf.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a subselect?

```
select * from posts 
where user_id IN (
    select user_followers.follower_id 
        from user_followers 
        where user_followers.user_id=$user_id) 
    OR posts.user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: It's still duplication it :(